# trigger 403 in php so that it shows the ErrorDocument

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-status-code-403

recently I set up custom-made error documents for my server.

I started with a 404 page and this works like a charm: file not found automatically shows the specified 404.php page.
However, with 403 I have some trouble. I set it up the same way, but I only get a blank page. It does not show the 403.php page as set in the .htaccess document.
Any ideas?

Here is my code:

.htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

php:

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 403 Unauthorized");
exit;
?>
```

Comment: The code you post *is* a blank page :-? What do you expect it to print?

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario He wants to force a 403 through *some.php* and the server automatically changes location to *403.php*

Comment: @DanFromGermany - You're right. I wrongly assumed it was the code in `403.php` (and needlessly wondered why he was sending the status code again).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error document defined in the server's config only get's loaded when *the server* (Apache) encounters a 403 error.

If you force an error through PHP, like send 403 status code, this happens in PHP not in Apache.

So when you already know *the site I want to render will fail due to unauthorized*, why leave it up to apache what will happen?

```
<?php 
header("HTTP/1.1 403 Unauthorized");
// either:
header("Location: /403.php");
// or:
include('403.php');
exit;
?>
```

> I started with a 404 page and this works like a charm:

Are you sure?

Do you have a script, sending 404 and get redirected to 404.php?
Or did you just open a non-existent URI and got redirected?

Comment: Correct. The ErrorDocument directive is used to determine what Apache should send back when it replies to a request that triggers the given status code. If you generate the status code yourself, Apache doesn't know or care: your PHP script is already the output.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Thanks for the confirmation!

Comment: Thanks, this exactly answered my question! I was searching around before, but it was not clear. Now it is, thanks again!

Comment: Tried the redirect option after sending `403` header but I see `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` header in response instead. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: In addition to my previous comment, even if I only respond with `header("HTTP/1.1 403 Unauthorized"); exit;`, I see `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` response header with `Content-Length: 0`

Answer (score 1):

Go to your server's real 403 page. (Go to a forbidden URL on your server, or go to any 403 page you like)

Right-click and select 'view source'. Select all the source and save it to file on your domain like: http://domain.com/403.php

Now go to your real forbidden page (or a forbidden situation in some part of your php) example: http://domain.com/members/my_forbidden_page.php

echo this code below before any HTML output or header! (even a whitespace will cause PHP to send HTML/TEXT HTTP Header and it won't work) The code below should be your first line!

```
<?php header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
$contents = file_get_contents('/home/your_account/public_html/domain.com/403.php', TRUE);
exit($contents);
```

I checked and verified with CPANEL Latest Visitors and it is registered as exact 403 event.